# I apply a link on Svg using php it works in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: php, redirect, svg

This is my code:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 990 400" style="enable-background:new 0 0 990 400;" xml:space="preserve">
<?php  
$pid=1;
echo"
<a href='plot_details.php?pid=$pid'>
<g id='Layer_2'>
    <rect id='XMLID_1_' x='15.4' y='14.3' class='st0' width='87' height='133.7'/>
</g>
</a>";
</svg>
```

When I hover the mouse to shape in chrome, it shows the link, but not in firefox. Need help.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not yet support the SVG 2 href attribute, it only supports the SVG 1.1 xlink:href attribute.

The SVG 2 standard is a work in progress, different UAs implement different parts of it. It will take time for the new standard to be finished and for UAs to support it.